# how come this override doesnt work magento 2

Tags: overrides, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default": "module_name/js/shipping-save-processor/default-override"
        }
    }
};
```

```
var config = {
    config:
    {
        mixins:
        {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default':
                { 'module_name/js/shipping-save-processor/default-override': true }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem. The var mixin method (in the answer above) won't work because there is a 'return storage.post' in the file. The way I did it was the following:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': {
            'Vendor_Module/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default-mixin': true
        }
    }
}
};
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default-mixin.js

```
define([
'ko',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
'mage/storage',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function (
ko,
quote,
resourceUrlManager,
storage,
paymentService,
methodConverter,
errorProcessor,
fullScreenLoader,
selectBillingAddressAction,
wrapper
) {
'use strict';

return function (defaultJS) {
    defaultJS.saveShippingInformation = wrapper.wrapSuper(defaultJS.saveShippingInformation, function (hash) {
        // this._super(hash); // execute default functionality
        // // add extended functionality here or modify method logic altogether


    });

    return defaultJS;
};
});
```

Comment: can i override Magento_Theme/web/js/view/messages.js like the way you have done?

Comment: It kind of depends on what kind of Javascript file it is. There are 4 different Mixin methods for the different JS files. You can see examples for them here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html Can you maybe accept this answer as the right answer if it worked for you? Under the upvote button is an accept answer button :)

Comment: @Sanne, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/348772/failed-to-load-the-component-m2

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this to override that file.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Content for this file is :

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default-mixin.js

Content for this file is :

```
define([
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
    'mage/storage',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/payload-extender'
], function (
    ko,
    quote,
    resourceUrlManager,
    storage,
    paymentService,
    methodConverter,
    errorProcessor,
    fullScreenLoader,
    selectBillingAddressAction,
    payloadExtender
) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        //You can override "saveShippingInformation" this function now here.
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Hope this information will work for you!

Comment: if i inspect on chrome and click network showuld i see default-mixin?

Comment: Also, you haven't answered what i asked 
why didn't map work?

Comment: Yes, @jibingeorge, we can able to check that file in network as well.

Comment: it didnt' pickup

Comment: It means above solution is not working for you ? @jibingeorge

Comment: no the mixin isnt working either.
I am trying to create a date picker at checkout i got that working but i cant get the value

Comment: Can you please try to clear your browser cache and then check ? Sometime it will not work due to browser cache or check in Private window.

Comment: I have cleared my cache and removed static still not working

Comment: are you able to file default-mixin.js this file in network when you load your page ?

Comment: mixin isn't getting picked at all

Comment: are you able to find that same js file in pub/static directory ?

Comment: Only the default nothing else
no mixin and no map Only the default

Comment: which Magento version you're using ?

Comment: Magento version 2.2.9

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/348772/failed-to-load-the-component-m2