# Failed to load the component. : M2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs, knockout

**phtml file:**

```
<?php 
$mycollection = $block->getMyCollection();
?>
<?php if ($mycollection) : ?>
    <div id="my-component" data-bind="scope:'myComponent'">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#my-component": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                   "components": {
                        "myComponent": {
                            "component": "Xyz_Pqr/js/my",
                            "template" : "Xyz_Pqr/my",
                            "mycollection" : <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->jsonEncode(array_values($mycollection)) ?>
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**js file:** Working good.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'mage/storage',
    'mage/template',
    'mage/url',
    'slick',
    'jquery/jquery.cookie'
], function ($, Component, ko, storage, mageTemplate) {
    'use strict';
    var self;
    return Component.extend({
});
});
```

**js file:** Not working.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Xyz_Pqr/js/model/resource-url-manager',
    'mage/storage',
    'mage/template',
    'mage/url',
    'slick',
    'jquery/jquery.cookie'
], function ($, Component, ko, resourceUrlManager, storage, mageTemplate) {
    'use strict';
    var self;
    return Component.extend({
});
});
```

**resource-url-manager.js**

```
define(
    [
         'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager'
    ],
    function (urlManager) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            /**
             * Retrieve style url
             * 
             * @return {string}
             */
            getStyleUrl: function () {
                var params = (urlManager.getCheckoutMethod() == 'guest') ? {} : {};
                var urls = {
                        'guest': '/my-style/get-by-my',
                        'customer': '/my-style/get-by-my'
                    };

                return urlManager.getUrl(urls, params);
            },
        };
    }
);
```

After defining **Xyz_Pqr/js/model/resource-url-manager** , giving error **[ERROR] Failed to load the "Xyz_Pqr/js/my" component.**

I have already run commands.

When i remove this (**'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager'**) from **resource-url-manager.js** file then component loading but giving error for **urlManager.getCheckoutMethod()**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you add entry in requirejs-config.js?

Comment: You need to add it first.

Comment: https://magepow.com/blog/how-to-display-html-file-by-knockout-js-in-magento-2/
you can see this article maybe it helps you

Comment: could you please share resource-url-manager,.js code

Comment: @nhungoduc, component already working,, not working after adding custom js file

Comment: @AnasMansuri, resource-url-manager.js file added

Comment: can you please verify with guest and customer urls

Comment: @RohanHapani , i have added more info

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named **"requirejs-config.js"** on below path
app / code / Company / modulename / view / frontend.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            resourceUrlManager: 'Xyz_Pqr/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        }
    }
};
```

and update your code as below

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'resourceUrlManager',
    'mage/storage',
    'mage/template',
    'mage/url',
    'slick',
    'jquery/jquery.cookie'
], function ($, Component, ko, resourceUrlManager, storage, mageTemplate) {
    'use strict';
    var self;
    return Component.extend({
});
});
```

please run

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

after changes

Comment: After adding , still getting same error.

Comment: dont know why still error. it should work'

Comment: i have added more details

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way to call Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager

Xyz_Pqr/js/model/resource-url-manager.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager'
    ],
    function ($, resourceUrlManager) {
        "use strict";

        return $.extend({

            /** Get url for update item qty and remove item */
            getUrlForUpdateItemInformation: function (quote, isRemove) {
                var params = (this.getCheckoutMethod() == 'guest') ? {cartId: quote.getQuoteId()} : {};
                var urlPath = (isRemove == true) ? 'remove-item' : 'update-item';
                var urls = {
                    'guest': '/guest-carts/:cartId/' + urlPath,
                    'customer': '/carts/mine/' + urlPath
                };
                return this.getUrl(urls, params);
            },

          
        }, resourceUrlManager);
    }
);
```

js file

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Xyz_Pqr/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ],
    function (quote,
              resourceUrlManager,
              storage,
              errorProcessor,
              customer,
              methodConverter,
              paymentService,
              shippingService,
              Loader,
              customerData) {
        'use strict';

        var itemUpdateLoader = ['shipping', 'payment', 'total'];

        return function (payload) {
            var isRemove = !('item_qty' in payload);

            if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                payload.cart_id = quote.getQuoteId();
            }

            Loader.startLoader(itemUpdateLoader);

            return storage.post(
                resourceUrlManager.getUrlForUpdateItemInformation(quote, isRemove),
                JSON.stringify(payload)
            ).done(
                function (response) {
                    if (response.redirect_url) {
                        window.location.href = response.redirect_url;
                        return;
                    }
                    quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                    paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                    if (response.shipping_methods && !quote.isVirtual()) {
                        shippingService.setShippingRates(response.shipping_methods);
                    }
                    customerData.reload(['cart'], true);
                }
            ).fail(
                function (response) {
                    errorProcessor.process(response);
                }
            ).always(
                function () {
                    Loader.stopLoader(itemUpdateLoader);
                }
            );
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quoteData')  quote.js

Comment: i have added more details

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you’re trying to call the code on a non-checkout page.

**Reason:**

In *‘Xyz_Pqr/js/model/resource-url-manager.js’* file you’re trying to load *‘Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager’* which loads *‘Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder’* file in its turn.

If you look at the file */vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/url-builder.js*, you will find the following part of code there:

```
return {
    ...
    storeCode: window.checkoutConfig.storeCode,
    ...
}
```

Since *window.checkoutConfig* variable is defined only on cart and checkout pages, the object cannot be loaded. And as a result, you’re getting the error.

**Solution:**

The easiest way solve this (but not the best one!) is to add the following code anywhere to your .phtml file:

```
<?php
$storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.checkoutConfig = {
        storeCode: '<?php echo $storeManager->getStore($block->getStoreId())->getCode(); ?>'
    };
</script>
```

Please, note, that this code is aimed only to emulate the missed variable. It would be much better to avoid using *‘Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager’* and use your own object instead.